# Why does Command + V behave like Page Up?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-yosemite, keyboard-events

On OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), the keyboard shortcut to paste the clipboard <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> behaves like Page Up.

Right now I'm able to reproduce this issue only in Mail and Evernote.

Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> does pageup, paste though.

I use Karabiner to remap some keys, but never <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> keys.
If I close Karabiner it doesn't change anything.

I have at some point used vim, the pbcopy terminal command, and some OS configuration from https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx

But I don't see why this could be a problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this or why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to replicate this issue in multiple users on your machine?  If so, then the issue is likely to have something to do with the modifications you outlined above (such as Karabiner or Vim), or some larger operating system related issue.

If you're not able to replicate the problem in multiple users, it could be related to a problematic preference file.  If you open a Finder window and navigate to ~/Library/Preferences, you could try moving the com.apple.HIToolbox.plist to your Desktop, logging out, then logging back in and testing again.

Let us know if either of those suggestions help!

Comment: I'll try that. Now that I think about it it could also be in ~Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict